# How to read test result reports on Travis CI?

Tags: gradle, travis-ci

For my builds on Travis, I want to be able to read the test results when there are failing tests to see the stacktrace of those failing tests. Currently, these reports are stored locally on the machine that runs the tests, so I am not able to access the local files where the reports are.

I also don't want to archive these files through Amazon S3 because that seems like way too much of a hassle.

Something like : [How to get surefire reports form Travis-CI build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684421/how-to-get-surefire-reports-form-travis-ci-build) seems like it could work, but also seems complicated.

Basically, I want to be able to read a local test result file from Travis without going through S3.

Comment: Can't you run your build tool in such a way it outputs more info when running the tests?

Comment: so something like, ./gradlew test --info instead of just ./gradlew test? I guess this could be a simple solution, but with the full report there could be more information with the failing test, which i think could be more helpful sometimes.

Comment: I'd just try to see if either `--info` or `--debug` produces enough info. If not, you can fine-tune your question.

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way to get useful output on the console about failing tests is to use the gradle test logging.

```
test {
    testLogging {
        events "failed"
        exceptionFormat "short"
    }
}
```

For details and more options here have a look at the according chapter in the gradle userguide: http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLoggingContainer.html

Comment: I think this is the simplest solution which does not pollute the build log as --info or --debug does. I eventually switched to use exceptionFormat "full" since the "short" one does not even contain exception messages.

Answer (score 12):

To expand on Rene Groeschke's answer, I found the following configuration to be a good compromise for Travis:

```
test {
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
        exceptionFormat "full"
    }
}
```

This will result in an output like the following:

```
com.package.SomeClassTest > testPass PASSED

com.package.SomeClassTest > testSkip SKIPPED

com.package.SomeClassTest > testFail FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<false> but was:<true>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
        at com.package.SomeClassTest.testFail(SomeClassTest.java:42)

3 tests completed, 1 failed, 1 skipped
```

The test report will still be generated, so you can consult it when running the tests locally.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `--info` to your command:

```
./gradlew test --info
```

If you want more, try:

```
./gradlew test --debug
```

Comment: it looks like trying those options still doesn't output why tests fail in travis, for whatever reason

Comment: Hmm, it does with me. I see assertion messages (i.e. `got X, expected Y`)