# How to download Android test report from Travis CI?

Tags: android, travis-ci, android-testing, android-instrumentation, travis-ci-cli

I am running Android instrumentation tests based on the Android testing library on Travis CI. Once the `connectedDebugAndroidTest` Gradle task finished it outputs the local path to a HTML test report which Gradle generates.

```
Execution failed for task ':example:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/travis/build/user/Example/Example/build/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html
```

- How can download or access the `index.html` and linked files?
- I looked into the [`travis` CLI](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb#readme) but could not find a download option there.
- Is there a way to access the Travis CI instance via SSH?

## Related

- [How to get surefire reports form Travis-CI build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684421/how-to-get-surefire-reports-form-travis-ci-build)
- [How to read test result reports on Travis CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614865/how-to-read-test-result-reports-on-travis-ci)
- [Is there a way to access and view html report in Travis CI for maven tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783728/is-there-a-way-to-access-and-view-html-report-in-travis-ci-for-maven-tests)